# How to get value of X in equation, d(M)/d(x) =constant using R?

Tags: r, eval, equation, solver, differentiation

I am trying to find optimal quantity for which I have to equate differentiation of Total Revenue Equation with Marginal cost. I dont know how to solve for x here. Differentiation works on expression type variable and returns the same, and solve() take numeric equation with only coefficient. I dont want to manually input coefficent.

```
TR = expression(Quantity * (40- 3*Quantity))
MR = D(TR,"Quantity")
Optimal_Quantity = solve(MR-MC) to get Q
```

The last line is pseudo code on what I want to achieve, Please help. I can manually enter the values, But wish to make it universal. MC = constant numeric value on RHS

Comment: It should be `MR = D(TR,"Quantity")`, please correct.

Comment: Yes Corrected !

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely understanding but if you want to optimize a function, find that functions derivative then find the derivative's zeros.

```r
TR <- expression(Quantity * (40- 3*Quantity))
MR <- D(TR,"Quantity")
class(MR)
#> [1] "call"

dTR <- function(x, const) {
  e <- new.env()
  e$Quantity <- x
  eval(MR, envir = e) - const
}

MC <- 0

u <- uniroot(dTR, interval = c(-10, 10), const = MC)
u
#> $root
#> [1] 6.666667
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 16.66667

curve(dTR(x, const = MC), from = -10, to = 10)
abline(h = 0)
points(u$root, u$f.root, pch = 16, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To make the function `dTR` more general purpose, I have included an argument `FUN`. Above it would only evaluate `MR`, it can now evaluate any function passed to it.
The code below plots `dTR` in a large range of values, from -10 to 100, hoping to catch negative and positive end points. Then, after drawing the horizontal axis, boxes the root between 20 and 30.

```r
dTR <- function(x, FUN, const) {
  e <- new.env()
  e$Quantity <- x
  eval(FUN, envir = e) - const
}

total.revenue <- expression(Quantity * (10- Quantity/5))             
marginal.revenue <- D(total.revenue, "Quantity")                                    
marginal.cost <- 1            

curve(dTR(x, FUN = marginal.revenue, const = marginal.cost), from = -10, to = 100)
abline(h = 0)
abline(v = c(20, 30), lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

```r
u <- uniroot(dTR, interval = c(20, 30), FUN = marginal.revenue, const = marginal.cost)
u
#> $root
#> [1] 22.5
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 7.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot Man! I was exactly looking for this. Getting the value of Q from D(TR)/D(Q) = MC

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas  It is showing Error for other equation **"Error in uniroot(dTR, interval = c(-10, 10), const = marginal.cost) : f() values at end points not of opposite sign"**                                                  
           `total.revenue <- expression(Quantity * (10- Quantity/5)) 
           marginal.revenue <- D(total.revenue,"Quantity")                        
           marginal.cost <- 1
           u <- uniroot(dTR, interval = c(-10, 10), const = marginal.cost)`

Comment: @anjali Try with `interval = c(20, 30)`. If errors like that occur, try to find two endpoints such that the function signs are different. For instance, run `curve(dTR(x, FUN = marginal.revenue, const = marginal.cost), from = -10, 100)` followed by `abline(h = 0);abline(v = c(20, 30), lty = "dashed")`.

Comment: So, we can keep a larger range too? And is it supposed to be the interval where root lies?

Comment: @anjali Yes, that's exactly it. `uniroot` only works if the search interval is an interval with a root. If there are 2 or more roots, the function can have the same sign on both em«nds and still have roots in the interval, see `y=x^2 - 1` in `[-2, 2]`. This example will give error. So it's up to the user/programmer to make sure the interval is right.